# Most optimized way to replace string in a set of files from a list

Tags: python, string, list, file, replace

1. I have a list that contains some strings.
2. I have a set of files that may or may not contain these strings.
3. I need to replace these strings with modified version of the string in every instance of the files. (eg. `string1_abc` -> `string1_xyz`, `string2_abc` -> `string2_xyz`). In essence, the substring that needs to be replaced and/or modified is common among the all the items in the list.

Is there any optimized or easy way of doing that? The most naive algorithm I can think of looks at each line in each file, and for each line, iterate over each of the items in the list and replace that using `line.replace` . I know this would give me an O(mnq) complexity where `m = number of files` , `n = number of lines per file` and `q = number of items in the list`

Note:

1. All the file sizes aren't very large so I'm not sure if reading line
   by line vs doing a file.read() into the buffer would be better?
2. q isn't very large either. The list is about 40-50 items.
3. m is quite
   large.
4. n can go upto 5000 lines.

Also, I've only played around with Python on the side and am not very used to it. Also, I'm limited to using Python 2.6

Comment: Is there a possibility that your target string will straddle a line break? i.e., `string1_abc==stri\nng1_abc` for this purpose?

Comment: Using generator expression might be better

Comment: A regex can do the match more efficiently (i.e. single pass). Capture the match and use it to look up what replacement you need to make.

Comment: @dawg  No. I think it's safe to assume it won't straddle line breaks.

Comment: @pvg Do you mean reading it into a buffer using .read()?

Comment: Is it possible to use `awk`? It may be less nice, but could be faster, as a language purpose-built for tasks like this,

Comment: @umayneverknow I mean not repeatedly scanning the same buffer over an over again which is clearly pretty inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo Python:

```
import glob
LoT=[("string1_abc","string1_xyz"), ("string2_abc","string2_xyz")]
for fn in glob.glob(glob_describes_your_files):
    with open(fn) as f_in:
       buf=f_in.read()    # You said n is about 5000 lines so 
                          #        I would just read it in
       for t in LoT:
           buf=buf.replace(*t)
    # write buf back out to a new file or the existing one 
    with open(fn, "w") as f_out:
        f_out.write(buf)
```

Something like that...

---

If the files are BIG, investigate using a [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) on the files and everything else is more or less the same.

Comment: Haven't used mmap but it seems like using .read seems easier. And I'm not sure how much of a difference it might make but the number is around 5000 lines not 500.

Comment: If the files are 5000 lines at say 80 characters per line your are talking about 400k bytes. Depending on the environment (Pi? Desktop? Phone?) yeah I would just use `.read()` since otherwise you would need to run the loop to replace many more times.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!